# How use wipefs with fdisk msg (15.04)

Tags: disk, fdisk

I have a 2TiB disk with exFat video on.
I discovered that *fdisk* gives this message:

---

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

/dev/sdd: device contains a valid 'ext4' signature, **it's strongly recommended to wipe the device by command wipefs(8)** if this setup is unexpected to avoid possible collisions.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x2e78422e.

Command (m for Help): p

Disk /dev/sdd : 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2e78422e

Command (m for Help): m

Help:

  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
```

---

- Can I continue to work like this: new write will not destroy anything?
- Can I save MBR with dd if=... of= with 512 bytes?
- What are the action to do to secure the disk without loss (no complete save actually)?

***EDIT*** after comment

```
sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdd
NAME --- FSTYPE ---  LABEL      ---   UUID                                 --- MOUNTPOINT
sdd  --- ext4   ---  3_HOME_2To ---   449db187-f86f-4a38-bf02-076f0beba3bd --- /2tera
```

Comment: What is supposed to be exFat video ?? Post ouput of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdd`. What do you want to achieve ? Current setup is fine if it works for you. There is no MBR so you want can't save it.

Comment: @solsTiCe I've had en *edit* in the question

Comment: @solsTiCe Videos are taken from an *exFat disk for Windows* ; files are like this `-rwx------  1 cylere cylere 14564660140 avril 24 06:09 noelle et miguel 21.mov*  
-rwx------  1 cylere cylere 14543014844 avril 23 14:50 noelle et miguel 22.mov*`

Comment: @solsTiCe I've done fdisk from root : **Disklabel type: dos**
Disk identifier: **0x307d4135** Identifier is different from the one I posted (no *umount* between). And mix *ext4/dos label* is always here.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I don't know if it a problem but I've a *dos label* with an *ext4 fstype* ? Perhaps it is good, but I do not know if I can have dammage when I will write

Comment: @solsTiCe and whye *fsdik* put attention to use *wipefs*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fdisk` doesn't like the fact that there is no MBR. You have a filesystem directly on disk **without** any partition and MBR.

This is fine for Ubuntu. Disregard this message from `fdisk` and don't use `wipefs`, otherwise you will **lose** all your data.